# Google cloud messaging service lost some messages

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

GCM lost some messages. For example, when from device A sending 20 messages and device B is in offline then gcm contains all messages, but when device b comes online then it receive random messages from 20 sent messages.

Here is my build.gradle dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    // Testing dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.1.1'
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.2.jar')
}
```

How can i get all messages from gcm.

Thank you

Comment: Check what's the "time to live" of the push you've sent.?

Comment: also check you have correct version of Playstore and Play services installed on the device Push is not getting received?

Comment: Please, see i updated my question

Comment: build.gradle dependency? There is no problem with this

Comment: "time to live" is set from our side or server side? and what is default value of it, if it is not set?

Comment: Sever side!
$fields = array(
    'collapse_key' => $coll_key,
    'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
    'data' => $message,
    'time_to_live' => $time_to_live,
);

Comment: thanks for your answer  @Dr. aNdRO, is Collapse_key value is same for all messages or different  for all messages?

Comment: I think adding the code you use to send the downstream messages would be of use.